# What is the effect of sample_weight in ROC plot?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I'm using the function `roc_curve` from the library `sklearn.metrics` to build ROC curves. I would understand: How the `weight_sample` parameter works in ROC curve calculation. Where is the effect of the `weight_sample` parameter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you mean sample_weight?